# Power transformers?

Tags: power, current, transformer

So I'm interested in welding, and I've seen people create viable welding power supplies by putting microwave transformets in series - I would like to do this, but the question had arisen - how does replacing the secondary coil of the transformer with an insulated coil turn it into a power transformer?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Every transformer is a power transformer. And so is the microwave transformer.

Comment: If your asking this question **don't do it.** Just buy a welding set  - *live long and prosper*

Comment: To reiterate Jim Dearden's comment, this falls very much into the category of "if you have to ask, you shouldn't do it". Microwave transformers are versatile, but are not to be trifled with.

Comment: DC to DC converters work better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a transformer to transfer electrical power from a source to a load, we call that a "power" transformer. The adjective is added to help understand the function of the particular transformer. For exemple, they also are "audio" transformer", "data" transformer, "gate driver" transformer, "isolation" transformer and many more depending on the specific application.

All types of transformer are made the same way. They all possess one primary and one secondary wound around a ferromagnetic core (laminated iron core for your microwave transformer). Both made of insulated wire. The use of the transformer for the application will determine if we "call" it a power transformer or another adjective.

Answer (score 1):

Welding transformers need to be *soft*, which means they have a reasonably high voltage as long there is no current flowing, and a pretty low voltage at high nominal current. That is because you want to break any insulating layers on the metal you weld while not suppling excess current which would melt holes in your metal sheets.

It makes no sense to use a transformer from a microwave oven for that. These have 2000V output voltage at roughly 700mA.

A proper welding transformer has about 50V open loop voltage and about 10V at 100A while welding. This is achieved by putting a bypass into the magnetic loop. Usually the air gap in that bypass is adjustable to control the welding current.

---

But all that is technology from yesterday. Buy a proper inverter welding kit for about $100 and you are fine. Much better than any simple welding transformer.

Answer (score 0):

The secondary coil is changed to a coil that has a much smaller number of turns and a much larger diameter wire. That way it reduces the secondary voltage from 2000 volts or so to 5 volts or so and increases the current to 100 amps or so. Connecting the secondary winding from two transformers in series doubles the voltage to 10 volts or so with the same 100 amps or so current.

The coil that is removed is insulated, but the insulation is a thin varnish-type material rather than thicker conventional insulation. When re-winding, it is best to use larger wire of the same type (magnet wire) rather than conventional wire. However, magnet wire may be more difficult to get, so many hobbyists use conventional wire.

You will need detailed instructions that can be found at various sites and Youtube clips. Read as many as you can. The clarity varies. Only quite old microwave ovens with heavy transformers can be used. Newer ones have electronic voltage converters rather than heavy transformers. If you can pick it up very easily, it has an electronic voltage converter inside.